# SQLite crash with several parallel processes - limitations of SQLite?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, sqlite

I have an .NET system that creates hundreds of processes (console apps) on demand.
Each process creates a different SQLite database so no concurrent access is being made to a single db.

It appears that when running a couple of hundreds of processes in parallel they start crashing when working with SQLite database. Remember, each process has its own db. However, the crash stops around ~40-45 parallel processes - steady.

Are there any limits/limitations for SQLite when working in many parallel apps?

Assemblies used to manipulate SQLite dbs:
System.Data.SQLite, System.Data.SQLite.EF6, System.Data.SQLite.Linq.

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: even there is no memory conflict, you may still have memory limit.

Comment: SQLite itself has no such limit. But you have to be more specific than just "crash".